# ConstraintLayout Performance

Tags: android, layout

Добрый вечер, стек.

**Ситуация:** есть `ConstraintLayout` в нём несколько вьюх с `wrap_content` высотой которые должны распологаться друг под другом.

**Вопрос:** необходимо ли указывать все 4 констреинта, тем самым образовывая вертикальную цепочку или достаточно для первой указать `constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` и дальше всем тоже задавать только 1 вертикальный констреинт.

**Более общий вопрос:** обязательно ли с точки зрения перфоманса указывать все 4 контреинта вьюхам или достаточно обходиться только необходимыми? Буду также благодарен за подробное объяснение работы констреинт лейаута "под капотом"

Comment: Для цепочки виджетов (горизонтальной или вертикальной) есть [связь chains](https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb). Все необходимые констраинты будут заданы автоматически

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Путем проб и ошибок я пришел к следующим выводам касательно перфоманса в xml разметке:

**1 - Ответ на мой вопрос** - что использовать цепочки ( `chains`) в `ConstraintLayout` (т.е. всегда привязывать обе стороны по одной оси) или только необходимую таков: на перфоманс практически никак не влияет, по замерам в Hierarchy Viewer разница колеблется то в ту, то в ту сторону и она минимальна. (Могу ошибаться, т.к. замерял только на одном лейауте, при других формах/связях и т.д. может разница и будет)
И пришел я к следующему выводу - единственная разница чисто визуальная. `chains` будут вам выравнивать элементы пропорционально по заданной оси. их стоит использовать чисто в данном случае. если же вам не нужно подобное выравнивание, то задавайте только необходимые констреинты.

**2- А теперь собственно по перфомансу**. Я думал что `ConstraintLayout` это панацея от всех бед, но оказалось что это далеко не правда. Он довольно долго просчитывает свои констреинты, **НО** быстрее чем аналогичные реализации через `LinearLayout` или `RelativeLayout` со вложеностями.

**И я вывел для себя идеальную формулу построения** `xml` : Если у вас есть возможность построить лейаут через `LinearLayout` без использования параметра `weight` (он заставляет дважды проходить по лейауту при построении) используйте его. Во всех остальных случаях `ConstraintLayout`. Ну и `CoordinatorLayout` там где он нужен :)